# Remove first character in line from text only if it matches defined character

Tags: python

I am receiving TCP data into a file. The data is meant for a POS printer.  as such I need to strip control characters and other unwanted info. I have successfully stripped everything except the letter 'a' . However I only need to strip the character if it needed. Not every line will begin with the letter 'a'. Essentially I need to strip the letter 'a' from each line only if it is present as the first character. I don't need to strip every 'a' from the whole file.
Below is what I am doing but it is stripping every 'a' in the file.

```
unwanted_chars="[a]"

def Rema():
    with open('Output.txt') as f:
        lines=list(f)
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        for c in unwanted_chars:
            line=line.replace(c,'')
        lines[k]=line

    with open('Output.txt','w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(lines))

while True:

        Rema()
```

Comment: `if data[0] in banned_char_list:` `data = data[1:]` ?

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question which is unrelated to stripping the letter `a`. Please edit it down to a [mcve]. You should be able to make an example which reproduces the issue without reading from a file or a network.

Comment: The answers you get will be a lot better if you do some debugging yourself first to narrow down the problem and condense it into a [mre]. Remember, people answering are _volunteering their time_ here and will usually just skip questions that are unclear or require too much effort to parse, so anything you can do to make it easier to understand and answer your question is helpful. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: I expect that instead of this: `unwanted_chars="[a]"`, you want this`unwanted_chars=["a"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.replace() iterates through an entire string and replaces all instances of the input with the new value given, so in this case, as you stated, all 'a's are being removed.

Strings can be called via indices just like lists in python so you could check if `line[0] == 'a'` and if so set the new line to be: `line = line[1:]`

Here is an example:

```
def Rema():
    with open('Output.txt') as f:
        lines=list(f)
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        for c in unwanted_chars:
            if line[0] == c:
                line = line[1:]
        lines[k]=line
```

This is very specific to removing the first letter if it is 'a'. If you want to check for other letters AS the first letter only this will work for a longer list in unwanted_chars. But if you wanted to go back and remove all instances of say "\n" as an example in a string you would again use .replace()

Answer (score 1):

If your printer doesn't like lines starting with an 'a' (for example), I'm guessing it's not going to like a line that started with 'aa' where you only remover the first 'a'.

How about using lstrip() for that:

```
def Rema():
    with open('Output.txt') as f:
        lines=(line.lstrip('a') for line in f)
    with open('Output.txt','w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer. Many thanks to Darren

```
def Rema():
with open('Output.txt') as f:
    lines=list(f)
for k, line in enumerate(lines):
    for c in unwanted_chars:
        if line[0] == c:
            line = line[1:]
    lines[k]=line
with open('Output.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('\r'.join(lines))
```